# flutter: check if object already exist in the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following code

```
class FavoriteItem {
  String headline;
  String content;
  String link;
  String publisheddate;

  FavoriteItem({this.headline, this.content, this.link, this.publisheddate});

  toJSONEncodable() {
    Map<String, dynamic> m = new Map();

    m['headline'] = headline;
    m['content'] = content;
    m['link'] = link;
    m['publisheddate'] = publisheddate;

    return m;
  }
}


class FavoriteList {
  List<FavoriteItem> items;

  FavoriteList() {
    items = new List();
  }

  toJSONEncodable() {
    return items.map((item) {
      return item.toJSONEncodable();
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

And i have initiated the class like this

`final FavoriteList favlist = new FavoriteList();` and i populate `favlist` with following code from json

```
if (items != null) {
   (items as List).forEach((item) {
     final favoriteitem =  new FavoriteItem(headline: item['headline'], content: item['content'], link: item['link'], publisheddate: item['publisheddate']);
     favlist.items.add(favoriteitem);
   });
 }
```

**Problem**

What I want to do is to check if object `favoriteitem` already exist in `favlist` before adding.

I tried using -

`favlist.items.contains`
`favlist.items.indexof` but didn't work

I am new to flutter/dart, can anybody please help me on this

Comment: @CopsOnRoad favlist.items.contains works but returns false, doesn't find object in list.`favlist.contains` gives undefined class error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`favlist.items.contains` and `favlist.items.indexof` are not working because I assume you are checking if `favoriteitem` exists (which it never will because it is a brand new object you just created). I would suggest checking by some unique identifier. Without knowing too much about your project, I would suggest something like the following:

Assuming your link field is unique per favorite item, the following should help:

```
//this is your new created favoriteitem to check against
final favoriteitem =  new FavoriteItem(headline: item['headline'], content: item['content'], link: item['link'], publisheddate: item['publisheddate']);

//find existing item per link criteria
var existingItem = items.firstWhere((itemToCheck) => itemToCheck.link == favoriteitem.link, orElse: () => null);
```

If `existingItem` is `null`, then nothing exists in your list that matches that link, otherwise it will return the first item matching that link.

Answer (score 15):

You could do something like this:

```
listB.addAll(listA.where((a) => listB.every((b) => a.id != b.id)));
```

Answer (score 5):

try this, two method were added, with it contains() should work properly

```
class FavoriteItem {
  String headline;
  String content;
  String link;
  String publisheddate;

  FavoriteItem({this.headline, this.content, this.link, this.publisheddate});

  toJSONEncodable() {
    Map<String, dynamic> m = new Map();

    m['headline'] = headline;
    m['content'] = content;
    m['link'] = link;
    m['publisheddate'] = publisheddate;

    return m;
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is FavoriteItem &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          headline == other.headline &&
          content == other.content &&
          link == other.link &&
          publisheddate == other.publisheddate;

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(headline, content, link, publisheddate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to the party and I think the API might have changed.

Now it is easy as using a boolean property called `hiveObject.isInBox` on a HiveObject to check if it is inside a box or not.

This works really well.

Answer (score 1):

In order not to add the same item twice, you can just try deleting the item from the list **(if it exist at all)** before adding the item as seen below:

```
favlist.item.removeWhere((it) => it.header == favouriteItem.header && it.content ==favouriteItem.content && it.link == favouriteItem.link ...)
```

then add the content afterwards:

```
favlist.item.add(favouriteItem)
```