# Check availability of Object in List -Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my Class

```
class TypeId {
   final int id;
   final int type;
   TypeId(this.id, this.type);
}
```

In Main function

```
void main() {
  List<TypeId> typeIds = [
    TypeId(1, 2),
    TypeId(1, 3),
  ];

  TypeId sample = TypeId(1, 3);

  if (typeIds.contains(sample)) {
    print('Its Working');
  } else {
    print('This Sucks');
  }  
}
```

I dont Know why its not comparing, If this is wrong please tell how to check

Comment: Two objects are not the same even if they have the same data, therefore `contains`  won't work. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454207/flutter-check-if-object-already-exist-in-the-list) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison must be implemented, because the objects are not the same.

```dart
class TypeId {
  final int id;
  final int type;
  TypeId(this.id, this.type);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return other is TypeId &&
      other.id == id &&
      other.type == type;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode ^ type.hashCode;
}
```